# I can't change from standard to clean theme

Tags: gwt, themes, gwt2

I remove the inherit of standard the from my module and replaced for:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
```

But my project still includes the standar theme, and after the clean:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/formulariorequerimientos3/gwt/clean/clean.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/formulariorequerimientos3/gwt/standard/standard.css">
```

So the styles are mixed and I see the horrible dialogbox of standard theme, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I wa including a module (one of UI utils) that inherits standard theme, so I replaced for clean

Answer (score 0):

Probably caching issue. Shut down you dev IDE and server serving the app .It's should really be in hosted mode.Clear browsers cache. Shut down your machine and restart. You will not have to do this all the time but sometimes caches get stuck. Also make sure there are not error in IDE and and check sever log as well (meaning logs from hosted mode server) to see any errors being thrown.
Check your War\Webapp if you see clean/clean.css then delete clean folder altogather. Also suggest Project->clean if you are using eclipse.